Deploying react app to godaddy using github
I am working on a react app that was hosted on godaddy currently every change that I want to make live means I am building the project and deleting all the previous file in cpanel and adding the new build file how can I make it automate whenever I push my code to a particular branch in my github that should automatically go live
Thank you
I did research on online and I found they are writing some code in github action main.yml file because I am new to this I am not getting anything how it's work how to modify that according to my need

To deploy react application on Godaddy, you can use Github actions. Github actions is very useful for CI/CD pipeline and you can make it very easily. I provide you sample Github actions yaml file.
name: Build & Deploy React Application with Github Actions // Ajust it if you want

on: // This is section that what event trigger Github actions. 
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env: // Here, you can set environment variables for your React application.
  REACT_APP_API_URL: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_API_URL }}

jobs: // In this jobs section, you will set all jobs to deploy your React application on your server.
  build-deploy:
    name: Build & Deploy on server
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest // ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Run build
        run: npm run build --if-present
    
      - name: Deploy on server
        uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@main
        with:
            SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
            ARGS: "-rlgoDzvc -i --delete"
            SOURCE: "build/"
            REMOTE_HOST: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_HOST }}
            REMOTE_USER: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_USER }}
            REMOTE_PORT: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_PORT }}
            TARGET: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_TARGET }}
            EXCLUDE: "/dist/, /node_modules/"

You can find more detailed guide here
